# Negating character using boost regular expression

Tags: regex, boost

I have following two statements. I want to find a single quote *only if* a backtick isn't present before single quote. I couldn't find a way to make it work. Could you help?

```
Var=`echo ${SOME_VAR} | awk -F "/" '{print $SOMETHING}`
echo 'some other thing'
```

The things I have tried:

```
(?!`.*)'
[^(`.*)]'
(?!<`).*'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to match the single quote **only if** backtick is **not** present before anywhere in the string. So first line in the example above should **not** match while the second one should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, without look-arounds (so this will work in all regex flavours):

```
^[^`]*'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iT4hR1/1)

Comment: sorry for delay in tagging your post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^[^`]*'.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU5nE3/5)**

Comment: I think I could not explain correctly. I want so that single quote is not matched if backtick is present **anywhere** before single quote.